# LR circuits - time constant meaning

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance, short-circuits

If you have a huge time constant in LR circuits, does this mean it takes a  long time to discharge and lose all current in circuit?

Similarly, if you have a tiny time constant in LR circuits, does this mean it takes a very short time to discharge circuit?

Comment: LR circuits do not contain capacitors.

Comment: Apologies! I meant, discharge & lose all current in circuit?

Comment: Yes, that's it. More info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The larger the time constant, the longer it takes for current to build up or decay in LR circuits, or for capacitors to charge or discharge in CR circuits.

Same with half-life of radioactive materials, which is a kind of time constant. Longer half-life means it takes longer to decay.

Comment: This is not necessarily true for the *decay* of current. If you open a switch in an LR circuit, the current doesn't keep flowing just because the time constant is long!

Comment: I am sorry, I don't see the relevance of your comment to my answer.

Comment: @alephzero would you please explain? You mean the current would stop instantly?

Answer (score 0):

One time constant specifies how long it takes to see 63% of the total change, as given by $1-e^{-1}$.  This means that a long time constant requires a long time to see 63% of the total change, while a short time constant requires a short time to see 63% of the total change.  Note that the time-constant concept is used because the exponential decay function never quite gets to zero mathematically.